# How to start clients together in SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm making a game. When two players accept to play together, I want to show a screen for 5 seconds telling them to get ready and start at the same time.

```
public class GameHub : Hub
{
    public void AcceptRequest()
    {
        Clients.Group("players").GetReadyToPlay();
    }
}
```

I send them a get ready signal, but I don't know what to do after that to start at the same time.

I've two problems:

- I don't want to use a timer on client side to avoid a malicious
  player break the starting process.
- I can pass a starting time in UTC,
  but the client clock may not be set correctly. How to start exactly
  together (a few seconds is not a problem).

**Ahh**

In my above method `AcceptRequest`, I can signal them to get ready, then sleep the thread for 5 seconds, then send a start signal to clients. Is this how it should be done?

Comment: The one who voted for close, how is this too broad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the 2 players are in their own group for this instance of the game.

Initiate a countdown that is sent to that group and on your UI have it display the values from the countdown. Instead of sleeping your thread, just countdown and broadcast to the client a "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "Go!" update.

The "Go!" could be on a separate broadcast method that actually starts the match.

Eventually you will have to deal with disconnect/reconnect events and how those affect the match.